# DevDemon Channel Videos searches return “The vimeo request failed!” after Update to 3.3

Tags: devdemon, channel-videos

I didn't have enough reputation points to simply respond to the answers on the other post dealing with this. I can confirm that I have updated to Channel Videos 3.3 which was released Aug 2, 2017. However, I am still receiving “The vimeo request failed!”. I am completely green when it comes to Expression Engine, though I have quite a bit of experience with PHP itself, as well as other CMS's. My main priority was to migrate this aging EE2 system to an Azure-Hosted VM before beginning the migration away from EE2. This one piece (Channel Videos) seems to be the only component not working. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

I am running EE v2.11.6 on PHP v5.6.31

Thank you.

**Additional Info**

After digging in a little bit, I find line 379 in `/themes/channel_videos/js/pbf.js`

```
function vimeoSubmitUrl ...

$.ajax({
 url: 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/' + id,,
 headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ChannelVideos.VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN},
 success: function(video_info) {
   if (typeof video_info.name == 'undefined') {
      loading.hide();
      inner.html("<p>The vimeo request failed!</p>");
      return;
   }
   ...
```

However, even though this simple ajax request should be all that is necessary to return the video name, when I look at Chrome Dev Tools, I'm seeing a GET request that looks like this:

`https://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=jsonp&full_response=1&method=vimeo.videos.getInfo&oauth_consumer_key=someconsumerkey&oauth_nonce=somenonce&oauth_signature=somesignature&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=sometimestamp6&video_id=1234343`

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It seems like the fix for the API issue occurs entirely in the js, so my js file was not updated correctly due to a configuration variable pointing to the wrong directory.